# learning public methods of a class

Tags: c#

I'm learning a bit of C# and I know a bit of c++ right now.

When I want to learn about a class's public methods - I look in the header file in C++- which C# doesn't have. Where do I get a good summary of a class's public methods without having to look in the source file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation, in Visual Studio using the object browser or IntelliSense or using reflection (either at runtime or using third-party tools).

Comment: If I'm getting a class from someone else - would it have documentation?  Where is the object browser in monodevelop.

Comment: I don't know, that depends on whether the someone else provides you with documentation. MonoDevelop [claims to have a Class Browser](http://monodevelop.com/download/monodevelop_2.0_released).

Comment: @MKaras: Even if it doesn't have a documentation (as in, readily readable file), there are documentation generation tools such as [Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) that you can run on compiled assemblies to generate stand-alone help files. If IntelliSense help texts has been supplied, that text will be included in the help files, otherwise, you will at least have a nicely browsable list of types and members from the API.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that does indeed work, but it isn't "documentation" in the sense I meant it. That doesn't show you anything you can't access through all other means mentioned, as it simply extracts XML comments that the other methods also show.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Ah, that wasn't clear from your answer. For example, the object browser doesn't show you anything you can't access through all other means, either.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways:

1) Read the documentation - [.NET Framework class library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or the appropriate one for used library.
2) Take a look at class in [Class view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx)
3) Use some metadata reading tool like [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4) The last in the list, but the most useful and most used is [Intellisense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43f44291.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't have header files, but byte code-compiled assemblies (i.e. `exe` and `dll` files) contain a section with metadata about namespace and namespace members, which is used by the runtime to discover types, methods, properties and so on. Also, Visual Studio uses it to offer its powerful intellisense.

Anyway, if you press F12 when cursor is on a method name, or any member (class, enumeration, ...), or you right-click there, Visual Studio will go to the definition of the whole member, and if such member has no source code in your machine, it will show metadata only:

[image]